# JavaScript's strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

If uncomment `body.children().each(calc_deep(1));` then i get `TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'attr'` on the `parseInt(deepest.attr('deep'))` string, but without uncomment you can check in console that you can call `deepest.attr('deep')`. What is that?

```
    var deepest;
    var calc_deep = function(i)
    {
        $(this).attr('deep',i);
        if(i>parseInt(deepest.attr('deep')))
            deepest=this;
        $(this).children().each(calc_deep(i+1));
    }
    var find_deepest = function()
    {
         body=$('body').children().eq(0);         
         body.attr('deep',0);
         deepest=body;
         //body.children().each(calc_deep(1));
    }
    find_deepest();
```

Comment: try cause the error here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `deepest` is the variable `body`, which is a jQuery object.  Later, when you assign deepest to `this`, it is a regular DOM element, which has no `attr` function.

You have a bigger problem - `this` is not pointing the element you think it is.  Call `$(this).children().each(calc_deep);` without the argument to the function.  To get the depth, just get it from the parent.  You are calling the function calc_deep and passing the (non-existant) return value to `each`.  You want to pass the function itself to each.

```
var deepest, index;
var calc_deep = function() {
    var $this = $(this); //cache jQuery this
    var i = $this.parent().data("deep") + 1;
    $this.data('deep', i);
    if (i > index) {
        deepest = $this;
        index = i;
    }
    $this.children().each(calc_deep);
}
var find_deepest = function() {
    body = $('body').children().eq(0);
    body.data('deep', 0);
    index = 0;
    deepest = body;
    body.children().each(calc_deep);
}
find_deepest();
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y65Vw/1)

Comment: You are awesome:) Also, why in your jsFidddle demo `deepest` is an array at the end?

Comment: `deepest` is a jQuery object, which has some array-like qualities.  It contains 0-n DOM elements which can be accessed like an array, in this case `[0]` gets the only DOM element in the set.  You could also do `deepest.attr("id")`

Answer (score 4):

`each` takes a function for an argument, you are passing it `undefined` - because you are calling the function first and then its return value is what `each()` gets.

Use `function() {calc_deep(1);}` instead.